# make center Text of custom button

Tags: java, blackberry

i am developing one app in which 9i have taken `CustomeButtonField` class for Make custom Button. in which i got custom button as expectation but Button of Text are Not Align Center.
can you please let me know that in CustomeButtonFiel that how can i make button text as Center.

**Here is Code**

```
import net.rim.device.api.system.Bitmap;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.*;

public class CustomButtonField extends Field
{
    Bitmap Unfocus_img, Focus_img, current_pic;
    int width;
    String text;
    Font font;   
    int custColor;
    CustomButtonField(int width, String text, Bitmap onFocus, Bitmap onUnfocus, long style,int custColor)
    {
        super(style);
        Unfocus_img = onUnfocus;
        Focus_img = onFocus;
        current_pic = onFocus;
        this.text = text;
        this.width = width;
        this.custColor = custColor;
    }
    protected void layout(int width, int height) 
    {
        setExtent(current_pic.getWidth(), current_pic.getHeight());        
    }
    protected void paint(Graphics graphics) 
    {
        try
        {
                FontFamily fntFamily = FontFamily.forName("BBAlpha Sans");
                font = fntFamily.getFont(Font.BOLD,20);              
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            font = Font.getDefault();

        }
        graphics.setFont(font);


        graphics.setColor(custColor); 


        graphics.drawBitmap(0, 0, current_pic.getWidth(), current_pic.getHeight(), current_pic , 0 , 0);
        graphics.drawText(text, width, 7);
        graphics.setDrawingStyle(Graphics.HCENTER, true);
    }
    protected void onFocus(int direction) 
    {
        super.onFocus(direction);
        current_pic = Unfocus_img;
        this.invalidate();
    }
  protected void drawFocus(Graphics graphics, boolean on) 
  {

    }
    protected void onUnfocus() 
    {
        super.onUnfocus();
        current_pic = Focus_img;
        invalidate();
    }
    public boolean isFocusable() {
        return true;
    }
    protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {
        fieldChangeNotify(0);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not understand why the down vote is given to my answer. It is not working or not a related answer? I know user asking for CustomeButtonField, I am providing one solution which is related to him/her; Not the mean that it is not a good answer; ok no problem, I deleted my answer;

Comment: I cant able to DV my reputation is 74

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace last 3 lines of the `paint` method with following lines:

```
int xText = (getWidth() - font.getAdvance(text)) / 2;
int yText = (getHeight() - font.getHeight()) / 2;

graphics.drawBitmap(0, 0, current_pic.getWidth(), current_pic.getHeight(), current_pic , 0 , 0);
graphics.drawText(text, xText, yText);
```

Comment: You can read this book, http://www.apress.com/9781430272250. `User Interface Basics`, and `Beyond the Basics of User Interfaces`, these chapters are good for understanding how to build customized Fields, FieldManagers.

Comment: I am not understand why the down vote is given to my answer. It is not working or not a related answer? I know user asking for CustomeButtonField, I am providing one solution which is related to him/her; Not the mean that it is not a good answer;ok no problem,I deleted my answer;

Comment: `This answer is not useful`, or something like that must have to be reason for any down vote. `I don't like the answer`, `It is not the best answer` or similar reasons are not acceptable in any means. But why you deleted your answer? It may be helpful to others, because you said that it solves the problem (in a different approach). But in this problem, `can you please let me know that in CustomeButtonFiel that` - this line actually emphasizes on solutions that can fix the implementation of the  `CustomeButtonFiel`.

Comment: You can always update and edit your answer. And it is possible to undelete your answer also.